# Why Eclipse generate toString includes only non-static fields?

Tags: java, eclipse, tostring, myeclipse

I want to use in myEclipse 10.1 (probably same issue in eclipse)

Source-> generate toString to build toString method automatically.

However there is no variables which has static identifier in FIELDS list.

Why?

And how can i represent also static fields in toString automatically?

Comment: `toString` is supposed to be a string representation of a specific instance of your class - why would you want static fields to be included?

Comment: I've a properties class. All are static fields. Actually I've no instance of it. And I want to log those properties.

This is a Q&A site right?

Comment: Yes it's a Q&A site but your question does not really make sense - so it seems that you will need to write it yourself (I don't think any IDEs would auto-include static fields in a `toString` method).

Comment: "Actually I've no instance of it." **Then it is impossible to call the toString() method, which is an instance method.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toString()` method is related to the `state` of the instance (same as `hashCode` and `equals`). `Static` fields do not belong to the instance, they belong to the `class`, thus do not belong, strictly speaking, to the instance state.

You can edit the `toString()` template in the dialog. At the `Generated code` there is `String format` in the drop down there is the default and an `Edit...` button.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that i could find for my case:

1-) replace " static" with ""

2-) Source -> generate toString with all fields that you want

3-) than again replace "public  " (two spaces) public static "

That's it!